# Boolean marker every time a string changes in a column, by group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'unit': {59: 'unit1',
  662: 'unit1',
  680: 'unit1',
  725: 'unit1',
  709: 'unit1',
  703: 'unit1',
  653: 'unit1',
  807: 'unit4',
  825: 'unit4',
  778: 'unit4',
  816: 'unit4',
  822: 'unit4',
  849: 'unit4',
  820: 'unit4',
  754: 'unit4',
  1031: 'unit3',
  1094: 'unit2',
  1008: 'unit2',
  1089: 'unit2',
  1044: 'unit5'},
 'Date_job': {59: datetime.date(2021, 6, 7),
  662: datetime.date(2021, 6, 14),
  680: datetime.date(2021, 7, 5),
  725: datetime.date(2021, 7, 26),
  709: datetime.date(2021, 8, 30),
  703: datetime.date(2021, 10, 11),
  653: datetime.date(2021, 10, 18),
  807: datetime.date(2021, 7, 19),
  825: datetime.date(2021, 7, 26),
  778: datetime.date(2021, 8, 23),
  816: datetime.date(2021, 8, 30),
  822: datetime.date(2021, 9, 6),
  849: datetime.date(2021, 9, 27),
  820: datetime.date(2021, 10, 4),
  754: datetime.date(2021, 10, 18),
  1031: datetime.date(2021, 9, 6),
  1094: datetime.date(2021, 7, 26),
  1008: datetime.date(2021, 8, 9),
  1089: datetime.date(2021, 10, 4),
  1044: datetime.date(2021, 6, 14)},
 'Vector': {59: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/3.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  662: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|5:1/8.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  680: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|14:1/4.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  725: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/3.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  709: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/3.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/5.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  703: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/4.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/6.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  653: ['A|14:1/9.0',
   'A|15:1/11.0',
   'A|16:1/12.0',
   'B|11:1/4.0',
   'B|2:1/4.0',
   'B|3:1/12.0',
   'B|4:1/12.0',
   'B|5:1/9.0',
   'B|6:1/6.0',
   'B|7:1/5.0'],
  807: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|4:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  825: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  778: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|8:1/7.0'],
  816: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|8:1/7.0'],
  822: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  849: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/3.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  820: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/5.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  754: ['A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|10:1/13.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|3:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/3.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|6:1/5.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0',
   'A|7:1/10.0'],
  1031: ['A|10:1/7.0',
   'A|12:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/10.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/12.0',
   'A|6:1/11.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/6.0',
   'A|9:1/2.0'],
  1094: ['A|10:1/7.0',
   'A|12:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/9.0',
   'A|6:1/11.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/4.0',
   'A|8:1/4.0',
   'A|8:1/3.0',
   'A|9:1/2.0'],
  1008: ['A|10:1/7.0',
   'A|12:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/9.0',
   'A|5:1/4.0',
   'A|6:1/11.0',
   'A|6:1/4.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|8:1/4.0',
   'A|9:1/2.0'],
  1089: ['A|10:1/7.0',
   'A|12:1/2.0',
   'A|5:1/9.0',
   'A|5:1/2.0',
   'A|6:1/11.0',
   'A|6:1/6.0',
   'A|7:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/3.0',
   'A|8:1/4.0',
   'A|9:1/2.0'],
  1044: ['A|10:1/6.0',
   'A|10:1/6.0',
   'A|5:1/4.0',
   'A|5:1/4.0',
   'A|6:1/10.0',
   'A|6:1/9.0',
   'A|6:1/9.0',
   'A|7:1/8.0',
   'A|7:1/8.0',
   'A|8:1/3.0']}}
```

which looks like this:

```
  unit    Date_job                                                                                                                   Vector
59    unit1  2021-06-07  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0] 
662   unit1  2021-06-14  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|5:1/8.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0] 
680   unit1  2021-07-05  [A|14:1/9.0, A|14:1/4.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]
725   unit1  2021-07-26  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0] 
709   unit1  2021-08-30  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0] 
703   unit1  2021-10-11  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0] 
653   unit1  2021-10-18  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0] 
807   unit4  2021-07-19  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|4:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]   
825   unit4  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]   
778   unit4  2021-08-23  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]   
816   unit4  2021-08-30  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]   
822   unit4  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]   
849   unit4  2021-09-27  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]   
820   unit4  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/5.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]   
754   unit4  2021-10-18  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]   
1031  unit3  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/10.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/12.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/6.0, A|9:1/2.0]    
1094  unit2  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/4.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|8:1/3.0, A|9:1/2.0]      
1008  unit2  2021-08-09  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]      
1089  unit2  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/6.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/3.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]      
1044  unit5  2021-06-14  [A|10:1/6.0, A|10:1/6.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/10.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|8:1/3.0]
```

The last column is a vector, here written as a list. As you can see, this vector can change over time for the same unit. I want to be able to tag the change between rows for each unit. I know how to do this for the entire dataframe but I haven't been able to apply `groupby` to this.

Here's what I know how to do:

```
df2["VectorChanged"] = df2["Vector"].shift(1, fill_value=df2["Vector"].head(1)) != df2["Vector"]
```

But, as you understand, it'll not a change of vector when units are changed (which is true but not applicable since we are not looking at the same unit):

```
unit    Date_job                                                                                                                   Vector  VectorChanged
59    unit1  2021-06-07  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   False        
662   unit1  2021-06-14  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|5:1/8.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   True         
680   unit1  2021-07-05  [A|14:1/9.0, A|14:1/4.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]  True         
725   unit1  2021-07-26  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   True         
709   unit1  2021-08-30  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   False        
703   unit1  2021-10-11  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   True         
653   unit1  2021-10-18  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   False        
807   unit4  2021-07-19  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|4:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
825   unit4  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
778   unit4  2021-08-23  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]     True         
816   unit4  2021-08-30  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]     True         
822   unit4  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
849   unit4  2021-09-27  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
820   unit4  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/5.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
754   unit4  2021-10-18  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
1031  unit3  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/10.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/12.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/6.0, A|9:1/2.0]      True         
1094  unit2  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/4.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|8:1/3.0, A|9:1/2.0]        True         
1008  unit2  2021-08-09  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        True         
1089  unit2  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/6.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/3.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        True         
1044  unit5  2021-06-14  [A|10:1/6.0, A|10:1/6.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/10.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|8:1/3.0]        True
```

The expected output is:

```
unit    Date_job                                                                                                                   Vector  VectorChanged
59    unit1  2021-06-07  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   False        
662   unit1  2021-06-14  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|5:1/8.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   True         
680   unit1  2021-07-05  [A|14:1/9.0, A|14:1/4.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]  True         
725   unit1  2021-07-26  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   True         
709   unit1  2021-08-30  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/3.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/5.0, B|7:1/5.0]   False        
703   unit1  2021-10-11  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   True         
653   unit1  2021-10-18  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/4.0, B|2:1/4.0, B|3:1/12.0, B|4:1/12.0, B|5:1/9.0, B|6:1/6.0, B|7:1/5.0]   False        
807   unit4  2021-07-19  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|4:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     False         
825   unit4  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
778   unit4  2021-08-23  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]     True         
816   unit4  2021-08-30  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|8:1/7.0]     True         
822   unit4  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
849   unit4  2021-09-27  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
820   unit4  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/5.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
754   unit4  2021-10-18  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|5:1/3.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|6:1/5.0, A|7:1/10.0, A|7:1/10.0]     True         
1031  unit3  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/10.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/12.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/6.0, A|9:1/2.0]      False         
1094  unit2  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/4.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|8:1/3.0, A|9:1/2.0]        True         
1008  unit2  2021-08-09  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/4.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        True         
1089  unit2  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/2.0, A|6:1/11.0, A|6:1/6.0, A|7:1/9.0, A|7:1/3.0, A|8:1/4.0, A|9:1/2.0]        True         
1044  unit5  2021-06-14  [A|10:1/6.0, A|10:1/6.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|6:1/10.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|6:1/9.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|7:1/8.0, A|8:1/3.0]        False
```

That is, the first row of each group i `False` since there is nothing to compare to, i.e., no change.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include your expected output?

Comment: Is possible groups are `1,1,1,2,5,1,1,3,4` ? It means e.g. 2 groups by `1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare shifted values and then set `False` for first values by `unit` use if performance is important, here `groupby` is not necessary:

```
df["Vector Changed"] = (df["Vector"].shift()
                                    .ne(df['Vector'])
                                    .where(df['unit'].duplicated(), False))
```

EDIT:

If possible consecutive duplicates by `unit` column use:

```
m = df["Vector"].shift().ne(df['Vector'])
g = df["unit"].shift().ne(df['unit']).cumsum()
df["Vector Changed"] = m.where(g.duplicated(), False)


print (df)
       unit    Date_job                                             Vector  \
59    unit1  2021-06-07  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...   
662   unit1  2021-06-14  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...   
680   unit1  2021-07-05  [A|14:1/9.0, A|14:1/4.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/1...   
725   unit1  2021-07-26  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...   
709   unit1  2021-08-30  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...   
703   unit1  2021-10-11  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...   
653   unit1  2021-10-18  [A|14:1/9.0, A|15:1/11.0, A|16:1/12.0, B|11:1/...   
807   unit4  2021-07-19  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....   
825   unit4  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....   
778   unit4  2021-08-23  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....   
816   unit4  2021-08-30  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....   
822   unit1  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....   <- again 1 groups
849   unit1  2021-09-27  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....   <- again 1 groups 
820   unit1  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....   <- again 1 groups 
754   unit4  2021-10-18  [A|10:1/13.0, A|10:1/13.0, A|3:1/6.0, A|3:1/6....   <- again 4 groups 
1031  unit3  2021-09-06  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/10.0, A|5:1/2.0...   
1094  unit2  2021-07-26  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|6:1/11.0...   
1008  unit2  2021-08-09  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/4.0,...   
1089  unit2  2021-10-04  [A|10:1/7.0, A|12:1/2.0, A|5:1/9.0, A|5:1/2.0,...   
1044  unit5  2021-06-14  [A|10:1/6.0, A|10:1/6.0, A|5:1/4.0, A|5:1/4.0,...   

      Vector Changed  
59             False  
662             True  
680             True  
725             True  
709            False  
703             True  
653            False  
807            False  
825             True  
778             True  
816             True  
822            False  
849             True  
820             True  
754            False  
1031           False  
1094           False  
1008            True  
1089            True  
1044           False
```

Comment: Shouldn't you sort by "unit" first? In case there are other rows between groups?

Comment: @not_speshal - If consecutive groups like in sample not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby` and `transform` like so:

```
df["Vector Changed"] = df.groupby("unit")["Vector"].transform(lambda x: x!=x.shift().bfill())
df["Vector Changed"] = df["Vector Changed"].mask(df.groupby("unit")["Vector"].transform("count")==1, False)

>>> df

       unit    Date_job Vector  Vector Changed
59    unit1  2021-06-07    ...           False
662   unit1  2021-06-14    ...            True
680   unit1  2021-07-05    ...            True
725   unit1  2021-07-26    ...            True
709   unit1  2021-08-30    ...           False
703   unit1  2021-10-11    ...            True
653   unit1  2021-10-18    ...           False
807   unit4  2021-07-19    ...           False
825   unit4  2021-07-26    ...            True
778   unit4  2021-08-23    ...            True
816   unit4  2021-08-30    ...            True
822   unit4  2021-09-06    ...            True
849   unit4  2021-09-27    ...            True
820   unit4  2021-10-04    ...            True
754   unit4  2021-10-18    ...            True
1031  unit3  2021-09-06    ...           False
1094  unit2  2021-07-26    ...           False
1008  unit2  2021-08-09    ...            True
1089  unit2  2021-10-04    ...            True
1044  unit5  2021-06-14    ...           False
```

Comment: It's almost right. the method does not handle solitons like ```unit3``` and ```unit5```. It should be ```False```.

Comment: Ah, so if there's just one row with a unit, it should automatically be `False`?

Comment: Yes, because there is nothing to compare to.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - See the edit. I think `mask`-ing units that have only one row is easier than modifying the `groupby`

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - Perfromance not important?

Comment: @jezrael Actually, it might be and I am checking that with your answer. It seems it is to be much faster on my actual dataframe.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - Super! Happy coding!